Closure of abelian algebraic subgroups is abelian subgroup
Let $G$ be an algebraic group and $H \leq G$ is abelian subgroup of $G$. Proof that $\overline{H}$ is also abelian.
Let $x \in H$. Let's define the homeomorphism $$\varphi_{x}: G \rightarrow G;$$ $$\varphi_{x}(g) = [x, g].$$
The preimage $\varphi^{-1}_{x}(e)$ is closed subset and $H \subseteq \varphi^{-1}_{x}(e).$ It means that $$\overline{H} \subseteq \varphi^{-1}_{x}(e).$$
In addition, $$\overline{H} \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{x\in H}\varphi^{-1}_{x}(e) = C_{G}(H).$$
Further, I do not understand what can be done to bring this reasoning to an end. I will be extremely grateful for any help!

Let $x\in\overline{H}$. Then $x\in C_G(H)$, which is equivalent to $H\leq C_G(x)$. As the centralizer is closed, it follows that $\overline{H}\leq C_G(x)$, which means $x$ commutes with all elements of $\overline{H}$.

It was so simple... Thanks a lot!
